# httpoison follow redirect after post

Tags: curl, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to mimic curl command with HTTPoison in a phoenix app

```
curl -k -L -b $COOKIES -c $COOKIES -d j_username=$USER -d j_password=$PASSWORD "$HOST/authenticated/j_security_check"
```

I am receiving an async response but am not seeing the body I would from curl. Am I missing another option in the HTTPoision call?

```
HTTPoison.post("HOST/authenticated/j_security_check", {:form, [j_username: 'USERNAME', j_password: 'PASSWORD']}, %{"Content-type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "User-Agent" => "test"}, hackney: [:insecure], hackney: [cookie: elem(acookie, 1).headers], follow_redirect: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

from the [hackney docs](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/blob/66a53291d3fef4f46f7baa99016725c7659aa022/doc/README.md#automatically-follow-a-redirection) (which HTTPoison is based on), hackney will only follow redirect on HTTP Post if the status is a 303:

> If the option {follow_redirect, true} is given to the request, the client will be able to automatically follow the redirection and retrieve the body. The maximum number of connections can be set using the {max_redirect, Max} option. Default is 5.
>
> The client will follow redirects on 301, 302 & 307 if the method is get or head. If another method is used the tuple {ok, maybe_redirect, Status, Headers, Client} will be returned. It will only follow 303 redirects (see other) if the method is a POST.

Comment: the POST response is 302. This is the same in `curl` as well; however, it redirects with a response. Whereas the call in HTTPoison doesn't. Maybe I am not sending the cookie correctly. The cookie comes from `acookie = HTTPoison.get "HOST/authenticated/identity", %{"User-Agent" => "test"}, hackney: [:insecure]` which is then passed in the above call. Does this look right? What I see from [hackney docs](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/blob/master/doc/hackney.md#cookies1)

Comment: In your question your using `HTTPoison.post`; hackney will only follow redirects if the status is a `303` when using post.  You will need to match on ` {ok, maybe_redirect, Status, Headers, Client}` and issue a `HTTPoison.get` yourself